# ServiceStack Register web service slow performance

Tags: mysql, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, servicestack

We noticed some performance bottlenecks in Service Stack web services especially the ones that comes out of the box like (Register) Web Service.

We ran a load-test using Visual Studio Load Test with the following parameters :

- 1K concurrent user.
- 1-minute duration.
- 5-seconds think time between test iterations.
- 5-seconds sample rate.

The results are so bad that they are actually preventing us from going live with a customer :

**19 Seconds Average Response Time**

Environment Specs are :

- 2 Web Front Ends (IIS) hosted in AWS Europe Region using c4.8xlarge EC2
  Instances(16GB-Ram & 8vCPU) behind a publicly exposed load balancer.
- MySql Database hosted in AWS RDS running inside (db.m4.4xlarge) EC2
  instance (64GB Ram, High Network Traffic, 16 vCPU)

We don't have special code or special global request filters .. only the default configuration .. we even tried connection pooling but that didn't help that much ..

What would be the reason behind such slow performance ? Appreciate your support as we are in a point where the customer is questioning the ServiceStack framework itself and we are starting to have doubts about that as well even though we loved every aspect of it.

Comment: This information isn't helpful without a tangible example that can be looked at, you likely have some poor performing code, incorrect API usage or some other issue with your environment, put together a stand-alone App with benchmarks that show the issue and we'll take a look,

Comment: Hi @mythz .. our custom web services are not suffering and are providing 0.6 - 1.0 seconds of average response time across 1k concurrent calls .. only the default 'Register' and 'Authenticate' web services are suffering .. is there any benchmarking for those methods ? was performance considered while writing their implementtion ? we are suspecting the Fluent Validator parts but that's only shooting in the dark .. Can you plz help ?

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah The Register Service needs to perform validation and setup a new User in the registered Auth Provider + invoke a number of Session/Auth callbacks. You can check the impl for [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) to see what it does, e.g If you don't specify `?AutoLogin=true` it'll be faster. If you're concerned about perf you should consider a Custom RegisterService to insert the User into the UserAuth table directly otherwise don't shoot in the dark, profile the app to see where the bottleneck is

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @mythz .. we solved the problem as in the accepted answer .. We love service stack but we think providing defaults such as authentication/authorization plugin should always consider performance and scalability as that is one of the principles in which service stack framework was built upon originally .. Anyway we love service stack but we think registration web service should be re-written to consider scalability in the future as it shows some duplicated queries and some heavy db logic better left for stored procedures perhaps.

Comment: Thanks mohammad zekrallah, Thanks mythz

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah Services called at runtime should be fast, but services like Register/Auth are called much less (i.e. 1 per user) and have other higher priority constraints like extensibility w/ custom app logic, support for multiple auth providers & auth repository backends, etc. Auth/Register would be useless if it couldn't be extended or if it only supported 1 Auth provider & Auth Repo. Having said that I've addressed this issue w/ lg tables in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9f96afcb455bbde0c88612b302c6199054a70f9b) available from v4.5.13 on MyGet cont.

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah Essentially there's now indexes on UserName/Email and OrmLiteAuthRepo will always try using the index first otherwise it will fallback to NonIndex/CaseInsensitive Search which can be disabled with `ForceCaseInsensitiveUserNameSearch = false`. An alternative way to allow case-insensitive matches but still use an index is to save the UserName/Email as lower case which can be enabled with `AuthFeature.SaveUserNamesInLowerCase = true`.

Comment: @mythz great to hear the news .. that was super fast .. thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came down to the bottom of this .. After hours of debugging and profiling register/login webs services, we found out that register code executes duplicated queries to the db (like check existing user validation logic etc..) that was even highlighted by Mini Profiler but that still wasn't the reason behind failing on only 1K concurrent users hitting the services which is very low number compared to the environment specs we ran on.

The reason was due to the following code getting called in both register/login :

```
private static TUserAuth GetUserAuthByUserName(IDbConnection db, string userNameOrEmail)
{
    var isEmail = userNameOrEmail.Contains("@");

    var userAuth = isEmail
        ? db.Select<TUserAuth>(q => q.Email.ToLower() == userNameOrEmail.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault()
        : db.Select<TUserAuth>(q => q.UserName.ToLower() == userNameOrEmail.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

    return userAuth;
}
```

The calls to `.ToLower()` got translated to SQL lower function getting called and when this is run concurrently and in a table where you have hundreds of thousands of rows, it would cause huge CPU spikes in the db server causing all the bottlenecks.

The fix was as simple as adding a dedicated lowered username and email fields in the database, updating UserAuth POCO to reflect those and finally adding an index to the new db columns and adjusting ormlite where condition to use the new columns.